# Problemas com permissão 777 e PHP

Tags: php, servidor

Eu estou com um problema envolvendo PHP e permissão 777. No meu servidor, existe uma pasta de uploads com permissão `777`, e um hacker conseguiu subir um arquivo `.php` nessa pasta, que alterou tudo que estava no meu server. Eu gostaria de saber como se faz isso e como eu posso evitar essa vulnerabilidade.

Comment: Você precisa barrar o upload por extensão. A questão que você não pode permitir o upload de um arquivo com etensão .php, .py, etc. Pois esses arquivos são interpretado pelo servidor quando requisitados. A função sua que faz upload precisa ser tratada para não permitir que esses arquivos sejam upados.

Comment: obrigado, você me ajudou muito assim, acho que deve ser isso mesmo pois meu script está sem esse filtro.

Comment: Exemplo, se você precisa upar fotos, então coloque o filtro para arquivos que terminem com o nome (.jpeg, .png, .jpg, .bmp, etc), diferente disso o upload não pode ser feito.

Comment: Como  a invasao ja foi feito aconselho, trocar nome de usuario root do banco de dados, se tiver acesso ssh, trocar nome e senha do usuario.

Comment: você também trabalham com essa permissão ou você acha que é desnecessário?

Answer (score 3):

Segue algumas dicas de segurança ao trabalhar com upload de arquivos no php:

- Armazene os arquivos de upload fora do diretório raiz da sua aplicação web. Dessa forma os arquivos não poderão ser acessados diretamente pelo navegador.
- Não armazene o arquivo de upload com o mesmo nome configurado no formulário de upload. Gere um nome randômico e faça o controle em banco de dados.
- Verifique se o mime-type do arquivo corresponde ao tipo de arquivo que deseja receber como upload. Não confie somente na extensão do arquivo ou no header HTTP Content-type. Por exemplo, caso queira garantir que o arquivo de upload seja uma imagem do tipo gif:

  ```
  <?php
  $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, "image.gif");
  finfo_close($finfo);

  if($mime_type == 'image/gif') {
      // arquivo é gif
  }
  ```